# Formulario Angular - Stack MEAN

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript, mongodb

Alguien me puede ayudar a enlazar un formulario en Angular con mi backend . Soy principiante y estoy atascada totalmente y el problema es que me queda 1 dia para hacer la entrega del mismo. He creado el backend y el frontend por separado ( así venía exigido por el curso que estoy haciendo ). El problema es que ahora no se como enlazarlos . He creado un servicio en Angular , el problema es que en mi componente tengo las funciónes y las validaciónes y no se como enlazarlo con mi servicio.

Este es mi componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { PersonModel } from './../../interfaces/persona';
import { PersonService } from './../../service/person.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-person',
  templateUrl: './person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person.component.css'],
  providers: [PersonService]
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
  
  do: String = "insert"
  position: any = 0

  person: PersonModel = {
    _id: "",
    name: "",
    surnames: "",
    age: "",
    dni: "",
    birthday: "",
    favouriteColour: "",
    sex: "",
    notes: ""
}

persons: Array<PersonModel> = []

  favouriteColours = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Rojo' },
    { id: 2, value: 'Azul' },
    { id: 3, value: 'Amarillo' },
    { id: 4, value: 'Verde' }
  ];

  constructor(public personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers()
  }

  getUsers(){
    this.personService.getPersons().subscribe(data =>{
      this.persons = data;
    })
  }


  add( form : NgForm ){
    
    if( this.do === 'insert' ){

      let birthDate  = new Date(this.person.birthday);
      let day = birthDate.getDay();
      let month = birthDate.getMonth();
      let year = birthDate.getFullYear();
      let ageNum = parseInt(this.person.age)

      this.person.birthday = `${day}/${month}/${year}`

      if(ageNum > 0 && ageNum <= 125){
      this.persons.push( this.person )
      }
      this.person = {
        _id: "",
        name: "",
        surnames: "",
        age: "",
        dni: "",
        birthday: new Date(),
        favouriteColour: "",
        sex: "",
        notes: ""
      }

    }
    else{
      this.persons[ this.position ] = this.person
      this.do = 'insert'
    }

    

  
  }
    // form.resetForm()
  


  delete( delPosition : number )    : void {
    this.persons.splice( delPosition , 1 )
  }
  update( upPosition : number ) : void {
    this.person  = this.persons[ upPosition ];
    this.do   = 'update'
    this.position = upPosition
  }
}
```

Y este mi service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { PersonModel } from './../interfaces/persona'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {
  

  person: PersonModel = {
    _id: "",
    name: "",
    surnames: "",
    age: "",
    dni: "",
    birthday: "",
    favouriteColour: "",
    sex: "",
    notes: ""
}

persons: Array<PersonModel> = []

  readonly URL_API = "http://localhost:5000/person/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   this.person =  new PersonModel();
  }

  registerPerson(person: PersonModel) {
    return this.http.post(this.URL_API, person);
  }

  getPersons() {
    return this.http.get<PersonModel[]>(this.URL_API);
  }

  editPerson(person: PersonModel) {
    return this.http.put(this.URL_API + `/${person._id}`, person);
  }

  deletePerson(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.URL_API + `/${_id}`);
  }
}
```

Entonces no se muy bien como colocar la función que he creado en el service.  De mi función add( ) del person.component.ts tengo que eliminar algun if ? Donde tengo que colocar la función del service dentro de mi funcion add( )  ? Si quito algun if, no me funcióna el boton de añadir en el front y no me añade ninguna persona.
Como debe de quedar al final la función add( ) ? 
Lo unico que he conseguido es que me muestre en mi app, mis usuarios registrados en la BBDD.

Gracias de antemano a tod@s por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: "Lo unico que he conseguido es que me muestre en mi app, mis usuarios registrados en la BBDD." Si hiciste esto, entonces enlazaste ya tu front y tu back... ya hiciste todo lo que tenias que hacer ahi... para entrar a otras rutas de tu back, es el mismo proceso... tal vez deberias ser mas clara con tu problema?

Comment: Por cada función que tengo en mi formulario.html , en el componente hago las validaciónes, por lo tanto en html con el onSubmit , tengo la función de add(personas) , edit(  ) y borrar( )... Entonces en el componente a esas funciónes les paso otras validaciónes, como por ejemplo la acción y si se borra un usuario que cambie de posición.  Para coger todos los usuarios he creado otra función aparte, que es la unica que he logrado enlazar con mi BBDD.

Comment: Entonces, tu problema es el front, el back o donde? porque es la unica que lograste enlazar a la base de datos? que paso cuando trataste de enlazar las otras?

Comment: Me salen errores por todos los lados, entiendo que mi problema esta en frontend. No se exactamente como conectar por ejemplo a la función add( ) , la que he puesto mas arriba.  En service tengo la función, pero entiendo que tengo que enlazarla al componente en la función add( ) ? Como hago eso, donde la tengo que poner ya que ahí tengo todo lo de arriba ?   No se si me explico muy bien , como he dicho soy principiante.

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar.. decis que lograste traer los usuarios.. o sea, ya conectaste a una funcion en tu back... porque no podes replicar la misma logica?

Comment: y si te salen errores, mostra el codigo que intentaste y aclara que error sale. es mucho mas facil que alguien pueda ayudarte asi

Comment: El codigo debe ir en la pregunta, con un ejemplo minimo reproducible de tu problema, inclusive el error. Y de esa forma, alguien va a poder ayudarte. Estoy tratando de que mejores tu pregunta para que alguien pueda ayudarte. usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion ahi.

Comment: Ya la he editado  no estoy con el pc ahora mismo para adjuntar los errores . Me he intentado explicar lo mejor posible

Answer (score 0):

Dando una revisada a los comentarios de tu pregunta, puedo entender que lograste implementar un servicio de Angular, además de utilizar la interfaz HttpClient, la cual necesariamente corresponde a un cliente [REST](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transferencia_de_Estado_Representacional), por lo que deduzco que tienes problemas para enviar la información usando un método HTTP distinto de GET.

Independientemente del caso planteado en el párrafo anterior, primaro hay que tener claro el uso de HttpClient, Servicios y Formularios de Angular.

La configuración de la función `registerPerson` de tu servicio `PersonService` sería esta:

```js
registerPerson(person: PersonModel) {
  return this.http.post(this.URL_API, person);
}
```

Siendo `this.URL_API` una propiedad de la clase `PersonService` con el valor de sólo lectura `'http://localhost:5000/person/'` y el tipo del JSON que se envía en el cuerpo de la solicitud corresponde a un objeto de tipo (o instancia) `PersonModel`. Ahora, por qué esto es importante, pues lo es porque a la hora de hacer una solicitud web, dicho endpoint debe estar preconfigurado para recepcionar dicha solicitud, que en el caso de esta función ha de ser un endpoint POST (puedes darle un vistazo también a los [métodos permitidos por expressjs](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.METHOD)).

Para implementar un servicio en un componente en Angular, basta con una sobrecarga en el constructor, como bien lo muestras en la pregunta:

```js
constructor(public personService: PersonService) { }
```

Teniendo lo anterior medianamente claro, es cuando entra en acción el uso del servicio, lo cual se hace ejecutando una llamada a alguno de los miembros de dicho servicio (de otra manera sería una dependencia inutilizada):

Y para ello, tomaré de referencia la función `add(form: NgForm)` y la propiedad `person`, ambos del componente, los cuales estarían directamente relacionados la función `registerPerson()` del servicio:

```js
add(form: NgForm) {
  ... // El código y validaciones que no aplican ahora
  this.personService.registerPerson(this.person).subscribe(
    responseBody => {
      ... // Aquí aplicarías la lógica según el cuerpo de la respuesta
    }
  ).unsubscribe();
}
```

Con esto, se puede ver que `HttpClient.post` retornará un [Observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable).

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

P.D: Para mayor información sobre `unsubscribe()`, puedes revisar [este artículo](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0)

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto en su tiempo, acabo de aprender React también y ya he entendido mucho mejor la conexión y las llamadas al backend . He indagado a fondo, estudiando y entendiendo muy bien el axios / fetch. Muchas gracias por la explicación y a todos por la ayuda ! 